# US B2 tourist visa 'admited until date'

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, visa-expiration

I have been admitted to the US for the fifth time now. I would like to know if I can use my admitted until date to go back into US although my visa has expired: 
e.g.: visa expires on November 18, admitted until March 17.

If I leave the US before November 18, can I use the 'until date' to re-enter the US?

Answer (score 3):

You need a valid (unexpired) visa to enter the US. The only exception is if you left the US for a brief trip of less than 30 days to only Canada or Mexico (and not to any other countries), you can re-enter the US under Automatic Revalidation and be admitted until the expiration of your previous I-94, even if your visa is expired.